# Comparison to an array of a value

Tags: perl

I'm still feeling my way though perl and so there's probably a simple way of doing this but I can find it. I want to compare a single value say `A` or `E` to an array that may or may not contain that value, eg `A B C D` and then perform an action if they match. How should I set this up?

Thanks.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html#How-can-I-tell-whether-a-certain-element-is-contained-in-a-list-or-array%3f

Answer (score 2):

You filter each element of the array to see if it is the element you are looking for and then use the resulting array as a boolean value (not empty = true, empty = false):

```
@filtered_array = grep { $_ eq 'A' } @array;
if (@filtered_array) {
    print "found it!\n";
}
```

Comment: This is the worst of all ways, as it compares *every* value in the target array, even after a match is found. Without using a hash, the best way is probably `any` from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List::MoreUtils).

Comment: If you want to stop when the first match is found then you can use a for loop. I agree that this would be terrible for a large list.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the list in an array then the only way is to examine each element individually in a loop, using `grep`, or `for` or `any` from [`List::MoreUtils`](https://metacpan.org/module/List%3a%3aMoreUtils). (`grep` is the worst of these, as it searches the *entire* array, even if a match has been found early on.) This is fine if the array is small, but you will hit performance probelms if the array has a significant size and you have to check it frequently.

You can speed things up by representing the same list in a hash, when a check for membership is just a single key lookup.

Alternatively, if the list is enormous, then it is best kept in a database, using `SQLite`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you stuck on arrays?

Whenever in Perl you're talk about quickly looking up data, you should think in terms of *hashes*. A hash is a collection of data like an array, but it is *keyed*, and looking up the key is a very fast operation in Perl.

There's nothing that says the *keys* to your hash can't be your data, and it is very common in Perl to index an array with a hash in order to quickly search for values.

This turns your array `@array` into a hash called `%arrays_hash`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

my @array = qw(Alpha Beta Delta Gamma Ohm);

my %array_index;

for my $entry ( @array ) {
    $array_index{$entry} = 1;  # Doesn't matter. As long as it isn't blank or zero
}
```

Now, looking up whether or not your data is in your array is very quick. Just simply see if it's a key in your `%array_index`:

```
my $item = "Delta";     #  Is this in my initial array?

if ( $array_index{$item} ) {
    say "Yes! Item '$item' is in my array.";
}
else {
    say "No. Item '$item' isn't in my array. David sad.";
}
```

This is so common, that you'll see a lot of programs that use the [map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) command to index the array. Instead of that `for` loop, I could have done this:

```
my %array_index = ( map { $_ => 1 } @array );
```

or

```
my %array_index;
map { $array_index{$_} = 1 } @array;
```

You'll see both. The first one is a one liner. The `map` command takes each entry in the array, and puts it in `$_`. Then, it returns the results into an array. Thus, the `map` will return an array with your data in the *even* positions (0, 2, 4 8...) and a 1 in the odd positions (1, 3, 5...).

The second one is more literal and easier to understand (or about as easy to understand in a `map` command). Again, each item in your `@array` is being assigned to `$_`, and that is being used as the key in my `%array_index` hash.

Whether or not you want to use hashes depend upon the length of your array, and how many items of input you'll be searching for. If you're simply searching whether a single item is in your array, I'd probably use `List::Utils` or `List::MoreUtils`, or use a `for` loop to search each value of my array. If I am doing this for multiple values, I am better off with a hash.

Comment: Beautiful answer, although I have to chide you for using `map` in void context – `$array_index{$_} = 1 for @array` works as well, but is more idiomatic. These days, I'd actually use a slice `@$_{@array} = () for \my %array_index;` and then ask if a specific element `exists`.